# R data.table intersection of all groups

Tags: r, data.table

I want to have the intersection of all groups of a data table. So for the given data:

```
data.table(a=c(1,2,3, 2, 3,2), myGroup=c("x","x","x",  "y",  "z","z"))
```

I want to have the result:

```
2
```

I know that

```
Reduce(intersect, list(c(1,2,3), c(2), c(3,2)))
```

will give me the desired result but I didn't figure out how to produce a list of groups of a data.table query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try using `Reduce` in the following way (assuming `dt` is your data)

```
Reduce(intersect, dt[, .(list(unique(a))), myGroup]$V1)
## [1] 2
```

Comment: I like it. It's simpler, easier to understand and definitely more in line with the approach the OP was using.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach.

```
nGroups <- length(unique(dt[,myGroup]))
dt[, if(length(unique(myGroup))==nGroups) .BY else NULL, by="a"][[1]]
# [1] 2
```

And here it is with some explanatory comments.

```
## Mark down the number of groups in your data set
nGroups <- length(unique(dt[,myGroup]))
## Then, use `by="a"` to examine in turn subsets formed by each value of "a". 
## For subsets having the full complement of groups 
## (i.e. those for which `length(unique(myGroup))==nGroups)`, 
## return the value of "a" (stored in .BY). 
## For the other subsets, return NULL.
dt[, if(length(unique(myGroup))==nGroups) .BY else NULL, by="a"][[1]]
# [1] 2
```

If that code and the comments aren't clear on their own, a quick glance at the following might help. Basically, the approach above is just looking for and reporting the value of `a` for those groups that return `x,y,z` in column `V1` below.

```
dt[,list(list(unique(myGroup))), by="a"]
#    a    V1
# 1: 1     x
# 2: 2 x,y,z
# 3: 3   x,z
```

Comment: @BondedDust -- OK, added some explanation.