# Optimize steps extend sequence date, intersect and compute by group with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge dataset, where I use data.table package due fast computing. Having this type of dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(
  gr1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 4),
  gr2 = rep(letters[3:6], each = 2),
  date1 = as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-04', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-04')),
  date2 = as.Date(c('2020-01-05', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-07', '2020-01-05', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-07')),
  value = 1:8
)
dt

   gr1 gr2      date1      date2 value
1:   A   c 2020-01-01 2020-01-05     1
2:   A   c 2020-02-01 2020-02-05     2
3:   A   d 2020-02-01 2020-02-02     3
4:   A   d 2020-02-04 2020-02-07     4
5:   B   e 2020-01-01 2020-01-05     5
6:   B   e 2020-02-01 2020-02-05     6
7:   B   f 2020-02-01 2020-02-02     7
8:   B   f 2020-02-04 2020-02-07     8
```

I want to sum `value` column on those dates (result of date-range sequence) present on all `gr2` that correspond to the same `gr1`. (independent calculation between `gr1`).

My workaround is:

1. Create a dataset with `date` column extending date ranges (`date1` and `date2`)

```
dt2 <- dt[, .(gr1, gr2, date = seq(date1, date2, by = 'day'), value), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

2. Add `is_shared` column if `date` is present on all `gr2` for each `gr1`, using `Reduce` and `intersect` functions, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513066/r-data-table-intersection-of-all-groups)

```
dt2[, date := as.character(date)]

dt3 <- split(dt2, by = 'gr1') %>% lapply(function(x) {
  
  dates <- Reduce(intersect, x[, .(list(unique(date))), gr2]$V1)
  x[, is_shared := date %in% dates][]
  
}) %>% rbindlist()
dt3

    gr1 gr2       date value is_shared
 1:   A   c 2020-01-01     1     FALSE
 2:   A   c 2020-01-02     1     FALSE
 3:   A   c 2020-01-03     1     FALSE
 4:   A   c 2020-01-04     1     FALSE
 5:   A   c 2020-01-05     1     FALSE
 6:   A   c 2020-02-01     2      TRUE
 7:   A   c 2020-02-02     2      TRUE
 8:   A   c 2020-02-03     2     FALSE
 9:   A   c 2020-02-04     2      TRUE
10:   A   c 2020-02-05     2      TRUE
11:   A   d 2020-02-01     3      TRUE
12:   A   d 2020-02-02     3      TRUE
13:   A   d 2020-02-04     4      TRUE
14:   A   d 2020-02-05     4      TRUE
15:   A   d 2020-02-06     4     FALSE
16:   A   d 2020-02-07     4     FALSE
17:   B   e 2020-01-01     5     FALSE
18:   B   e 2020-01-02     5     FALSE
19:   B   e 2020-01-03     5     FALSE
20:   B   e 2020-01-04     5     FALSE
21:   B   e 2020-01-05     5     FALSE
22:   B   e 2020-02-01     6      TRUE
23:   B   e 2020-02-02     6      TRUE
24:   B   e 2020-02-03     6     FALSE
25:   B   e 2020-02-04     6      TRUE
26:   B   e 2020-02-05     6      TRUE
27:   B   f 2020-02-01     7      TRUE
28:   B   f 2020-02-02     7      TRUE
29:   B   f 2020-02-04     8      TRUE
30:   B   f 2020-02-05     8      TRUE
31:   B   f 2020-02-06     8     FALSE
32:   B   f 2020-02-07     8     FALSE
```

3. Filter *shared dates* and compute calculation by `gr1`

```
dt4 <- dt3[is_shared == TRUE][, .(value = sum(value)), by = .(gr1, date)]
dt4

   gr1       date value
1:   A 2020-02-01     5
2:   A 2020-02-02     5
3:   A 2020-02-04     6
4:   A 2020-02-05     6
5:   B 2020-02-01    13
6:   B 2020-02-02    13
7:   B 2020-02-04    14
8:   B 2020-02-05    14
```

Problem:

- Huge size of `dt2`
- `split` and `lapply` step produces crash on my system (15Gb RAM and 4Gb of Swap)

Possible optimizations:

- Avoid dt2 and dt3 objects, due expand dates from date ranges.
- I tried to use `.I` when creating date-sequence by row, but I have an error `'from' must be of length 1`. So I changed to `1:nrow(dt)`, that creates an unnecessary column called `nrow` (removed on posterior calculations).
- Do not convert `date` to character class on `dt2` (needed when search with `%in%` into `lapply`

**EDIT:** Adding real case

```
dt <- data.table(
  id1 = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 4)),
  id2 = rep(c(10, 20, 30), each = 4),
  id3 = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2), 3),
  gr  = rep(1:2, 6),
  date1 = as.Date(rep(c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-05'), 6)),
  date2 = as.Date(rep(c('2020-01-10', '2020-01-12'), 6)),
  value = 1:12
)

dt

    id1 id2 id3 gr      date1      date2 value
 1:   1  10   A  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10     1
 2:   1  10   A  2 2020-01-05 2020-01-12     2
 3:   1  10   B  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10     3
 4:   1  10   B  2 2020-01-05 2020-01-12     4
 5:   1  20   A  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10     5
 6:   1  20   A  2 2020-01-05 2020-01-12     6
 7:   1  20   B  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10     7
 8:   1  20   B  2 2020-01-05 2020-01-12     8
 9:   2  30   A  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10     9
10:   2  30   A  2 2020-01-05 2020-01-12    10
11:   2  30   B  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-10    11
12:   2  30   B  2 2020-01-05 2020-01-12    12
```

**The aim is:**

- Create/expand dataset with a `date` column consisting on dates between `date1` and `date2`
- For each combination of `id1`-`id2`-`id3`, filter *shared* dates present on **all** `gr`
- Sum the corresponding `value`

Comment: I always worry when I see “output would be like”. It usually mean the question is incomplete. Please specify the exact and complete value that would allow checking.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I could complete the workflow, I changed the title and trying to optimize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, with benchmarking against the OP's and @r2evan's solutions:

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse) # for the function "fndistinct"
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(d1, d2, v, g2) {
  # needed for r2evan's solution
  tmp <- as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(
    cbind(data.table(v=v, date=Map(seq, d1, d2, by = "days")), g2=g2),
    date))
  allg3 <- unique(g2)
  tmp[, .SD[all(allg3 %in% g2),], by = date][, .(value = sum(v)), by = date]
}
```

OP's solution

```
f1 <- function(dt) {
  # OP solution
  dt2 <- dt[, .(gr1, gr2, date = seq(date1, date2, by = 'day'), value), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
  
  dt3 <- split(dt2, by = 'gr1') %>% lapply(function(x) {
    
    dates <- Reduce(intersect, x[, .(list(unique(date))), gr2]$V1)
    x[, is_shared := date %in% dates][]
    
  }) %>% rbindlist()
  dt3[is_shared == TRUE][, .(value = sum(value)), by = .(gr1, date)]
}
```

Option 2:

```
f2 <- function(dt, idcols = grep("id", names(dt)), grcol = grep("gr", names(dt))) {
  d <- as.integer(dt$date2 - dt$date1) + 1L
  setDT(
    c(
      lapply(dt[, ..idcols], rep.int, times = d),
      list(
        date = as.Date(sequence(d, dt$date1), origin = "1970-01-01"),
        value = rep.int(dt$value, d),
        # the count of unique gr by ids
        n = rep.int(fndistinct(dt[[grcol]], dt[, ..idcols], 1), d)
      )
    )
  )[
    # aggregate value by id and date
    # keep only if the count is equal to the number of unique gr
    , .(value = if (n[1] == .N) sum(value) else value[0]),
    c(names(dt)[idcols], "date")
  ]
}
```

Benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(dt),
                               r2evans = dt[, fun(date1, date2, value, gr2), by = gr1],
                               f2 = f2(dt, 1L, 2L),
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>       f1  5042.1  5390.60  6225.412  6182.55  6763.70  9123.5   100
#>  r2evans 11061.0 11836.35 12555.882 12145.10 12865.85 19127.9   100
#>       f2   694.9   835.70   885.403   879.80   932.80  1127.3   100
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.table(
  gr1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 4),
  gr2 = rep(letters[3:6], each = 2),
  date1 = as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-04', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-04')),
  date2 = as.Date(c('2020-01-05', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-07', '2020-01-05', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-07')),
  value = 1:8
)
```

For the "real case" data:

```
f2(dt)
#>     id1 id2 id3       date value
#>  1:   1  10   A 2020-01-05     3
#>  2:   1  10   A 2020-01-06     3
#>  3:   1  10   A 2020-01-07     3
#>  4:   1  10   A 2020-01-08     3
#>  5:   1  10   A 2020-01-09     3
#>  6:   1  10   A 2020-01-10     3
#>  7:   1  10   B 2020-01-05     7
#>  8:   1  10   B 2020-01-06     7
#>  9:   1  10   B 2020-01-07     7
#> 10:   1  10   B 2020-01-08     7
#> 11:   1  10   B 2020-01-09     7
#> 12:   1  10   B 2020-01-10     7
#> 13:   1  20   A 2020-01-05    11
#> 14:   1  20   A 2020-01-06    11
#> 15:   1  20   A 2020-01-07    11
#> 16:   1  20   A 2020-01-08    11
#> 17:   1  20   A 2020-01-09    11
#> 18:   1  20   A 2020-01-10    11
#> 19:   1  20   B 2020-01-05    15
#> 20:   1  20   B 2020-01-06    15
#> 21:   1  20   B 2020-01-07    15
#> 22:   1  20   B 2020-01-08    15
#> 23:   1  20   B 2020-01-09    15
#> 24:   1  20   B 2020-01-10    15
#> 25:   2  30   A 2020-01-05    19
#> 26:   2  30   A 2020-01-06    19
#> 27:   2  30   A 2020-01-07    19
#> 28:   2  30   A 2020-01-08    19
#> 29:   2  30   A 2020-01-09    19
#> 30:   2  30   A 2020-01-10    19
#> 31:   2  30   B 2020-01-05    23
#> 32:   2  30   B 2020-01-06    23
#> 33:   2  30   B 2020-01-07    23
#> 34:   2  30   B 2020-01-08    23
#> 35:   2  30   B 2020-01-09    23
#> 36:   2  30   B 2020-01-10    23
```

Comment: good benchmark. But your functions does not take care of `all(allg3 %in% g2)` as @r2evans does, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure what you meant initially. In that case the answer is simpler (and faster). See the updated answer.

Comment: It seems to work fine. But on my real case, I have three different `gr1` like columns. One of them, in near future, could be character type.Considering your note about sorting, they will be sorted too, but different `gr1` can have same `gr2`. I'm having some warning, on intermediate data.table, about reciclyng due `rep.int(g, g)`. Maybe it's caused by `group` (first time I see it), that I've modified to `attr(group(dt[, 1:4], 0, 1), "group.sizes")`

Comment: r2evans solution was fine because I added more `gr1s` on `by =` and that's it, but your function's speed is awesome

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it should affect the expected output. Can you update your example so it more closely matches your actual data?

Comment: I've added an closer example

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. There was an error in the unique `gr` count logic. I've updated the answer to handle variable number of `id` columns.

Comment: Also, I don't think the new solution requires the columns to be sorted.

Comment: I've applied both functions, r2evans and yours, on a real case of initial 850K rows. r2evans' function does the job on 15 minutes, and yours on incredibly 9 seconds. Because I was looking for the most optimized way to do the job, I consider your solution as the best one. Although I really appreciate the effort, dedication and patience of all the people who have participated. With all answers I have a very valuable material to continue learning. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```r
fun <- function(d1, d2, v, g2) {
  tmp <- as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(
    cbind(data.table(v=v, d=Map(seq, d1, d2, by = "days")), g2=g2),
    d))
  allg3 <- unique(g2)
  tmp[, .SD[all(allg3 %in% g2),], by = d][, .(value = sum(v)), by = d]
}

dt[, fun(date1, date2, value, gr2), by = gr1]
#       gr1          d value
#    <char>     <Date> <int>
# 1:      A 2020-02-01     5
# 2:      A 2020-02-02     5
# 3:      A 2020-02-04     6
# 4:      A 2020-02-05     6
# 5:      B 2020-02-01    13
# 6:      B 2020-02-02    13
# 7:      B 2020-02-04    14
# 8:      B 2020-02-05    14
```

There is not (yet? [data.table#2146](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146) and [data.table#3672](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3672)) a `data.table`-internal unnest function, and the discussion in those issues suggests that `tidyr::unnest` is efficient-enough at this to preclude jumping into one themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try with my real data, hope it does not crash. One doubt, with `uniqueN(gr2) > 1` this does not ensure it's on all `gr2` on the same `gr1`, right? On `gr1=A` maybe there are 3 different `gr2` but on `gr1=B` maybe exists 5 different `gr2`. `date` should be included if exists on all `gr2` of `gr1=A` OR on all `gr2` of `gr1=B`. For that reason I used `intersect`

Comment: Your question used to say *"shared that belongs"* instead of the current *"present on all"*, so yes, this would need to be updated to account for your changed constraints. See my edit. (You will likely want to test with sample data that actually includes both "does" and "does not" satisfy this constraint.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The question was edited to many times. Next time, I will try to upload the most approximate final question, sorry. And thanks a lot for your time. I'm going to try your function

Answer (score 0):

The approach below uses `data.table` non-equijoins and chaining to avoid materializing any intermediate results. Unsure if it could potentially run into memory issues with your full size data.set, but I believe it should be performant.

```
## Generate an index of all dates included in ranges
Index <- data.table(date = seq.Date(from = dt[,min(date1)],
                                    to = dt[,max(date2)],
                                    by = 1))

## Create an extra column since data.table dt[dt2, ...] style
## joins modify the original key columns
Index[, dateKey := date]    

## Set keys ahead of time
setkey(dt,date1,date2)
setkey(Index,dateKey)

## Perform a non-equijoin to expand to the equivalent of dt2
Index[dt, on = .(dateKey >= date1, dateKey <= date2)][
  ## Determine whether dates are shared
  , is_shared := .N > 1, keyby = .(gr1,date)][
    ## Subset only shared dates and sum values by gr1 and date
    is_shared == TRUE, .(value = sum(value)), keyby = .(gr1,date)]
```

As far as benchmarking goes, the results demonstrated so far by @jblood94 *(measured in microseconds)* for a 8-12 row dataset are typically unlikely to be representative of performance for the larger dataset. The dataset you provided was excellent for demonstrating the input and output you desired in a digestible manner, but generating a much larger synthetic dataset with group counts, date range lengths, and an overall timespan similar to your current dataset would be necessary truly compare performance.

The code below demonstrates an approach to generate an arbitrarily large dataset and compare current proposed approaches, running only one time each. Both the `data.table` approach outlined in this answer and @jblood94's `f2()` solution appears to scale very nicely. However, I noticed different approaches gave different results with this synthetic data, not sure at first result is "right". *Pretty sure I'm running into an artifact of comparing different edit revisions of the OP/@jblood94's question and answer.*

Also, another apternative shows how converting date columns to the `data.table` `IDate` class boosts performance slightly.

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse) # for the function "fndistinct"
library(dplyr)

## Number of rows in synthetic data
N = 1e5

## Larger date ranges and mean duration will impact resulting
## intermediate result sizes significantly
start <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2022-12-31")
range <- seq.Date(from = start,
                  to = end,
                  by = 1)
meanDuration <- 60
sdDuration <- meanDuration/2

## Cardinality of groups will also impact results
gr1Set <- as.character(seq_len(100))
gr2Set <- as.character(seq_len(20))

dt <- data.table(
  gr1 = sample(gr1Set, N, replace = T),
  gr2 = sample(gr2Set, N, replace = T),
  date1 = sample(range, N, replace = T),
  date2 = as.Date(NA),
  value = sample(1:10, N, replace = T)
)[order(gr1,gr2,date1)]

dt[, date2 := date1 + ceiling(pmax(1,rnorm(N, mean = meanDuration,sd = sdDuration)))]
str(dt)
## Create copies so functions each get a "clean" set of data
## Since data.table modifies by reference
dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)
dt4 <- copy(dt)
dt5 <- copy(dt)
```

Function definitions:

```
fun <- function(d1, d2, v, g2) {
  # needed for r2evan's solution
  tmp <- as.data.table(tidyr::unnest(
    cbind(data.table(v=v, date=Map(seq, d1, d2, by = "days")), g2=g2),
    date))
  allg3 <- unique(g2)
  tmp[, .SD[all(allg3 %in% g2),], by = date][, .(value = sum(v)), by = date]
}

f1 <- function(dt) {
  # OP solution
  dt2 <- dt[, .(gr1, gr2, date = seq(date1, date2, by = 'day'), value), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
  
  dt3 <- split(dt2, by = 'gr1') %>% lapply(function(x) {
    
    dates <- Reduce(intersect, x[, .(list(unique(date))), gr2]$V1)
    x[, is_shared := date %in% dates][]
    
  }) %>% rbindlist()
  dt3[is_shared == TRUE][, .(value = sum(value)), by = .(gr1, date)]
}

f2 <- function(dt, idcols, grcol) {
  d <- as.integer(dt$date2 - dt$date1) + 1L
  setDT(
    c(
      lapply(dt[, ..idcols], rep.int, times = d),
      list(
        date = as.Date(sequence(d, dt$date1), origin = "1970-01-01"),
        value = rep.int(dt$value, d),
        # the count of unique gr by ids
        n = rep.int(fndistinct(dt[[grcol]], dt[, ..idcols], 1), d)
      )
    )
  )[
    # aggregate value by id and date
    # keep only if the count is equal to the number of unique gr
    , .(value = if (n[1] == .N) sum(value) else value[0]), 
    c(names(dt)[idcols], "date")
  ]
}


matt <- function(dt){
  ## Generate an index of all dates included in ranges
  Index <- data.table(date = seq.Date(from = dt[,min(date1)],
                                      to = dt[,max(date2)],
                                      by = 1))
  ## Create an extra column since data.table dt[dt2, ...] style
  ## joins modify the original key columns
  Index[, dateKey := date]
  
  ## Set keys ahead of time
  setkey(dt,date1,date2)
  setkey(Index,dateKey)
  
  ## Perform a non-equijoin to expand to the equivalent of dt2
  Index[dt, on = .(dateKey >= date1, dateKey <= date2)][
    ## Determine whether dates are shared
    , is_shared := .N > 1, keyby = .(gr1,date)][
      ## Subset only shared dates and sum values by gr1 and date
      is_shared == TRUE, .(value = sum(value)), keyby = .(gr1,date)][]
  
}

mattIDate <- function(dt){
  ## Generate an index of all dates included in ranges
  Index <- data.table(date = as.IDate(seq.Date(from = dt[,min(date1)],
                                               to = dt[,max(date2)],
                                               by = 1)))
  ## Create an extra column since data.table dt[dt2, ...] style
  ## joins modify the original key columns
  Index[, dateKey := date]
  
  ## Convert to data.table IDates for performance
  dt[,date1 := as.IDate(date1)]
  dt[,date2 := as.IDate(date2)]
  ## Set keys ahead of time
  setkey(dt,date1,date2)
  setkey(Index,dateKey)
  
  ## Perform a non-equijoin to expand to the equivalent of dt2
  Index[dt, on = .(dateKey >= date1, dateKey <= date2)][
    ## Determine whether dates are shared
    , is_shared := .N > 1, keyby = .(gr1,date)][
      ## Subset only shared dates and sum values by gr1 and date
      is_shared == TRUE, .(value = sum(value)), keyby = .(gr1,date)][]
  
}
```

And benchmarking for 100,000 input rows:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(dt1),
                               r2evans = dt2[, fun(date1, date2, value, gr2), by = gr1],
                               f2 = f2(dt3, 1L, 2L),
                               matt = matt(dt4),
                               mattIDate = mattIDate(dt5),
                               #check = "identical",
                               times =  1)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#        f1  8269.9858  8269.9858  8269.9858  8269.9858  8269.9858  8269.9858     1
#   r2evans 37229.5579 37229.5579 37229.5579 37229.5579 37229.5579 37229.5579     1
#        f2   821.1306   821.1306   821.1306   821.1306   821.1306   821.1306     1
#      matt  1335.4477  1335.4477  1335.4477  1335.4477  1335.4477  1335.4477     1
# mattIDate  1037.2043  1037.2043  1037.2043  1037.2043  1037.2043  1037.2043     1
```